# What is the maximum SP you can get per day?

Tags: dust-514

Dust 514 has a set SP for passive, and a cap for active SP gain.

So assuming you cap your SP for the day, and use no boosters, how much SP do you gain total?

For bonus points: how much can you gain with boosters?

Comment: Best I could find was a guess at 500,000 SP per week. Also they said once it would take 7 years to cap a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daily allowance of 27,200 active SP per day, w/o boosters. Passive is approx. 24,000 SP w/o boosters. Multiple those #'s by 1.5 & you get approx. totals with boosters.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your answer on gaming.stackexchange.com. It is not very detailed yet; can you add reference links that back up your numbers, such as a wiki or official announcement?

Comment: It is worth noting that the daily skill cap has been removed in favor of a weekly sp cap. https://forums.dust514.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=54331&find=unread